# Android set text left right padding inside MaterialButton to zero

Tags: android

[image]

I need to display the full text in 1 line inside the button, no ellipsize. How can I achieve the intended result?

I tried insetLeft & insetRight it doesn't work. padding also not working.

Current Code

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_continue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@drawable/button_background_tint_selector"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:text="Continue Continue Continue Continue Continue Continue"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

Comment: As you set `android:layout_width="0dp"` so it will acquire remaining space of width. If you don't have enough space to set width then obviously it'll not showing full text inside button.

Comment: In other way, You can use `android:ellipsize="marquee"` to show full text with scrolling effect. Use below property to achieve marquee effect it might help to show full text within button in single line.
`android:ellipsize="marquee"  
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"  
android:scrollHorizontally="true"  
android:singleLine="true"`